# Starting bash script

Tags: linux, bash, busybox

Hello I have such problem. I have init scripts, and I must run syslogd (busybox), so I have such code:

```
...
"$__start_program" $OPTIONS
....
```

If I

```
echo "$__start_program $OPTIONS"
```

it prints

```
/sbin/syslogd -s 512 -l 6 -L -O "/var/log/a.log"
```

I see this process in `ps`, but actually syslog don't start (there is no messages in log file about start and `logger` don't write something to log at all). But if I run this script manually from command line (with same arguments) it works fine. Can some one help me with this problem?

Comment: There are suspicious quotes around `"/var/log/a.log"`, they ptobably should not be there.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Could you clarify what are the contents of `$__start_program` and `$OPTIONS`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a string to store commands, that's not what they're for. The [link provided in the comments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) contains some good discussion on the potential problems that this may cause.

It's not clear from the question where one string starts and the other ends but you should use a function to achieve what you are trying to do. Something like this:

```
log_daemon() {
    param_s="$1"
    logfile="$2"
    /sbin/syslogd -s "$param_s" -l 6 -L -O "$logfile"
}
```

Then call it from your script like:

```
log_daemon 512 /var/log/a.log
```